# Como realizar um slider horizontal de 250px por clique?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Bom dia pessoal, usei a API do instagram para mostrar as fotos do meu perfil no website e não encontrei nenhuma solução ***carousel*** que não conflitasse com jQuery do Magento, então comecei a fazer a mão mesmo.

Com a própria API do Instagram eu calculei o comprimento total da `div.insta` que eu precisa usando multiplicação e soma da quantidade e largura das fotos e atribui o resultado dessa matemática ao `width` dela mesma.

Por sua vez a div principal com um `overflow:hidden` esconde essa largura total ajudada por esse atributo, ou seja, a div que se abre pra receber todas as fotos continua além do comprimento do site, lógico e o conteúdo é escondido pela div principal.

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora eu preciso fazer com que a `div.insta` deslize horizontalmente para frente e para trás através destes botões `prev / next` que eu criei.

[**O site !!!!**](http://storemud.axitech.com.br)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O método [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) do `jQuery` pode resolver o seu problema. Você pode alterar a margem da sua div `.insta` de acordo com o tamanho das fotos, e o `animate()` te dá esse efeito de transição. Se você copiar

```
jQuery( '.right-direction' ).on( "click", function() {
  jQuery('.insta').animate({
        marginLeft: "-=250px",
    },1000, function() {
        console.log ('moveu');
    });
});
```

direto no console do seu site, você vai ver que o botão direito agora faz com que todo o seu conteúdo se mova para a esquerda. Você pode usar a mesma lógica para o botão esquerdo. Vale lembrar que o código acima não verifica se as imagens acabaram ou não, ele apenas transiciona a margem. Essa verificação vai depender do seu número de imagens que você tiver.

**EDIT**:

Acredito que o código a seguir reproduza o efeito que você está procurando:

```
var offset = 0;

var TOTAL_IMAGENS = 10; //contei a partir do seu HTML. Você pode chegar neste valor na maneira como achar melhor

if (offset === 0){
    jQuery('.left-direction').hide();
}

jQuery( '.right-direction' ).on( "click", function() {
  jQuery('.insta').animate({
        marginLeft: "-=250px",
    },1000, function() {
        ++offset;
        console.log(offset);
        jQuery('.left-direction').show(); 
        if(offset === TOTAL_IMAGENS){
            jQuery('.right-direction').hide();
        }
    });
});

jQuery( '.left-direction' ).on( "click", function() {
  jQuery('.insta').animate({
        marginLeft: "+=250px", 
    },1000, function() {
        --offset;
        console.log(offset);
        jQuery('.right-direction').show();
        if(offset === 0){
            jQuery('.left-direction').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Veja que este código não está completamente otimizado (em vários momentos, executo as linhas `jQuery('.left-direction').show();` e `jQuery('.right-direction').show();` sem necessidade, mas, como prova de conceito, acredito que o código esteja bom. Se você quiser ser mais objetivo, pode controlar com duas flags se os botões estão lá ou não.

Basicamente, eu defini uma variável chamada `offset` que vai ser incrementada ou decrementada conforme você clica pelos botões de esquerda e direita. Como, no início, não vai ter nenhuma imagem na esquerda, eu já escondo a flecha da esquerda (se bem que isso você pode definir no CSS e economizar um pouco no seu JS). Se o meu `offset` cresce a ponto de ser o número total de fotos, eu escondo a flecha da direita. A lógica é basicamente essa. Como eu disse, esse código está longe de ser ótimo, mas acredito que já te dê uma boa noção.

Comment: Caio, me ajuda agora a parar no início e no fim das fotos? Eu tenho um ***largTotal*** se servir pra alguma coisa.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius, veja minha resposta editada